# Delphi: how to create custom component containing other controls just like TMainMenu does it

Tags: delphi

I need to create a component (TMaster), very similar to TMainMenu. My component (It is actually an visible control) will contain a tree of other components (TSlave) (not visible for now). Its not a problem actually, but i need designer to create declaration in Form's declaration for each TSlave. 
It is very similar to how TMainMenu does it: when you add new menu item in menu designer, you also may see them in Form's declaration and also can use them in code just like others components/controls on form.
How can i do that? I replicated TMainMenu/TMenuItem structure (basics) and able to see my proerty desgnwe and add items. Items are successfully added to dfm file (i can see them in text mode) but i dont see declarations in TForm1. Also i dont see them in Structure Explorer (menu items are displayed there).

Thanks.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406567/creating-a-component-with-named-sub-components

Comment: Thanks alot. Exactly what i wanted!