# Does TCollection.Add actually add?

Tags: delphi

I've started to use the TCollection class in Delphi XE and I found the answer at [Using TOwnedCollection descendant in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050724/using-townedcollection-descendant-in-delphi) to be a good starting point. TCollection manages a list of TCollectionItems. However I noticed that TCollection.Add doesn't seem to add an TCollectionItem to a Collections array and indeed my testing appears to confirm that. The code in TCollection itself is:

```
function TCollection.Add: TCollectionItem;
begin
  Result := FItemClass.Create(Self);
  Added(Result);
end;
```

FItemClass is the object type that will be created and I thought added to the TCollection object. The Added() method is deprecated and appears to be an old notification method. Nowhere do I see the Result being added to the collection. How should one add a TCollectionItem to a TCollection?

Comment: Isn't TCollection an abstract class? Maybe the descendants override one of the mwthods. Just a thought

Comment: After looking through the source code I have a partial answer to the above question. The act of creating a TCollectionItem creates an entry in the TCollection object because the Collection object is passed to the CollectionItem constructor. I was forgetting to call the inherited method in the constructor because the inherited method in turn calls setCollection which does that actual adding. However I am still not entirely sure why Add is called Add.

Answer (score 5):

`TCollectionItem.Create(Collection: TCollection)` calls `TCollectionItem.SetCollection`, which adds the item to `Collection`:

```
procedure TCollectionItem.SetCollection(Value: TCollection);
begin
  if FCollection <> Value then
  begin
    if FCollection <> nil then FCollection.RemoveItem(Self);
    if Value <> nil then Value.InsertItem(Self);
  end;
end;
```

It's called `TCollection.Add` because it creates the collection item, and the item constructor adds the item to the containing collection. So `TCollection.Add` indeed creates the item (adding the item to itself in the process), and returns a reference to that newly created item. (You use that reference to set the properties of the `TCollectionItem` itself.)